# How can I stop Google 日本語入力 from changing type of input all the time?

Tags: discussion

I recently installed Google 日本語入力 on my Windows 10 PC. I used to have it on my old Windows 7 PC and it worked flawlessly, but now it seems the configuration got really messy.

When I press the Caps button, the input changes from `あ` to `_A`. I want the Caps button to just change the text to uppercase if I'm typing the alphabet.

I also want to only change from `あ` to `A` with `CTRL+Back quote` (or `CTRL+Space` if possible), instead of with the Caps button, within the same IME.

Also, another big problem I have, is that the IME tries to guess whether I'm going to use `あ` or `A`, and it changes it automatically without telling me. Each time I focus (click) on a different Window, it tries to guess (wrong 100% of the time) and changes the input accordingly.

Conclusion, what I want is to have the Google 日本語入力 be in one type of input constantly (static) without changing automatically, AND also to be able to change from Japanese to English/Spanish with one Keyboard combination.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think this question is better fitted to http://superuser.com